# Set the uiscrollview contentSize according to number of items in row, UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios6

Trying to set the uiscrollview contentSize according to number of items in a row in UICollectionView. Below is my code, i am trying.

```
 CGFloat width = 55;

float w = width * rows;
if(w > 320.0)
{
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 290);
    CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(w, 290);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
}
else
{
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 290);
     CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(320, 290);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
}
NSLog(@"w:%f", w);
```

Here rows are number of items or cells in a row. Above is not giving accurate results. I am not getting how to set the width accurately to get proper results.

```
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20;

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 12, 10, 10);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CGSize retval =  CGSizeMake(30, 31);
return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of the code (if /else) has the same code for both if and else... You're basically saying if X do Y, else do Y

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: Ok. Then I don't think you need to set the scrollview size, the collection view will do it for you

Comment: but that is set for vertical scroll for horizontal i am using scrollview

Comment: above code will scroll left to right and for up and down scroll "[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];"

Comment: I mean w*rows.  Whatever you are multiplying w by

Comment: it is the number of cells in rows that is coming from server.

Comment: somewhere it is 4, 10 or 20. As its value the same will be the number of items in row. Suppose section have 100 cells and rows = 10 so section will have 10x10.

Answer (score 0):

Actually their is no need to set the UIscrollView content Size since UICollectionView will adjust the contentSize automatically.

Comment: but that is set for vertical scroll for horizontal i am using scrollview.